# Getting null data when calling get method on another class

Tags: java, methods, apache-kafka, parameter-passing

I am trying to display the data from another class `Transaction` within my `Application` class. I created a new instance of `Transaction` and passed it into the `sendUserNotification` method but when I call the get methods on the data, it comes back as null.

`Application Class`

```
public class Application {
    private static final String TOPIC = "suspicious-transactions";
    private static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application kafkaConsumerApp = new Application();

        String consumerGroup = "user-notification-service";
        if (args.length == 1) {
            consumerGroup = args[0];
        }

        System.out.println("Consumer is part of consumer group " + consumerGroup);

        Consumer<String, Transaction> kafkaConsumer = kafkaConsumerApp.createKafkaConsumer(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, consumerGroup);

        kafkaConsumerApp.consumeMessages(TOPIC, kafkaConsumer);

    }

    public static void consumeMessages(String topic, Consumer<String, Transaction> kafkaConsumer) {
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, Transaction> consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

            if (consumerRecords.isEmpty()) {
                //do something
            }

            for (ConsumerRecord<String, Transaction> record : consumerRecords) {
               Transaction transaction =  new Transaction();
               sendUserNotification(transaction);

                System.out.println(String.format("Received record (key: %s, value %s, partition: %d, offset: %d",
                        record.key(), record.value(), record.partition(), record.offset()));
            }
        }
    }

    public static Consumer<String, Transaction> createKafkaConsumer(String bootstrapServers, String consumerGroups) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer .class.getName());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroups);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);

        return new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
   }

    private static void sendUserNotification(Transaction transaction) {
        // Print transaction information to the console
        String h =transaction.getUser();

        System.out.println(String.format("Sending user %s notification about a suspicious transaction of %f in their account originating in %s", h, transaction.getAmount(), transaction.getTransactionLocation()));

    }
```

`Transaction Class`

```
public class Transaction {
    private String user;
    private double amount;
    private String transactionLocation;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getTransactionLocation() {
        return transactionLocation;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void setTransactionLocation(String transactionLocation) {
        this.transactionLocation = transactionLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Transaction{" +
                "user='" + user + '\'' +
                ", amount=" + amount +
                ", transactionLocation='" + transactionLocation + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    /**
     * Kafka Deserializer implementation.
     * Deserializes a Transaction from JSON to a {@link Transaction} object
     */
    public static class TransactionDeserializer implements Deserializer<Transaction> {

        @Override
        public Transaction deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Transaction transaction = null;
            try {
                transaction = mapper.readValue(data, Transaction.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return transaction;

        }
    }
```

`Output`

```
Consumer is part of consumer group user-notification-service
Sending user null notification about a suspicious transaction of 0.000000 in their account originating in null
Received record (key: dkelly9283, value Transaction{user='dkelly9283', amount=1653.32, transactionLocation='China'}, partition: 0, offset: 12
Sending user null notification about a suspicious transaction of 0.000000 in their account originating in null
Received record (key: msmith2015, value Transaction{user='msmith2015', amount=50.43, transactionLocation='California'}, partition: 1, offset: 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass a value to user field. reference variable fields( in this case String user) are initialized as null by default in java. you can use constructor or setUser()

after creation of new instance of Transaction:

```
Transaction tr = new Transaction();
tr.setUser("User"); 
tr.setAmount(100); 
tr.setTransactionLocation("Location");
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I forgot to do that haha.

Comment: Are you to provide an example of what you mean? I tried setUser(key) and passed in a record.key variable which worked for the user but I cannot do the for getting the amount and location.

Comment: @orangeblue98 you should use your methods "public void setAmount(double d)" and "public void setTransactionLocation(String s) ". l wrote an example